# Ideas to improve the site

Tags: discussion, beta

According to the [Area51 page for Portuguese Language Stack Exchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64172/portuguese-language), we need to improve some things here:

[image: Area51 page for Portuguese Language Stack Exchange]

- Improve the visits per day;
- Improve the answer ratio;
- Improve the questions per day;
- improve the avid users (improve the other 3, this also improves);

So, I'm open this discussion to get ideas to get it done.

Here are some ideas:

**Question Titles**

Create a task force to apply some SEO techniques to attract more users to the site from search engines.

**Create "courses"**

I did not see it in any of the other language sites of Stack Exchange, but the idea is to create some questions that work like "courses to learning Portuguese". For example a question for explain verbs and so on. I know this strays a bit from the Q & A format, but it is an idea under construction, we can do something!

More ideas?

Comment: good idea. We have to work hard to put this site on th road. Well done :)

Comment: I love the spirit here, but please don't focus too much on the stats on that page. A few months ago, [we updated how we look at the health of beta sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites), and most of those numbers turned out to be less important than we thought they were in the past. We just haven't gotten around to updating what gets displayed there, yet.

Comment: Thx for the link @Pops, this was very instructive and I had not seen before. Anyway, regardless of the statistics page, I think we can have this space to discuss ideas for improving the site, right?

Comment: Yes, absolutely! Brainstorm away!

Comment: The numbers are way higher by now! \o/

Comment: I think more questions should either be deleted or improved. There are a lot of silly questions asked....

Answer (score 9):

I use other language SE sites (specifically [German SE](https://german.stackexchange.com/)) and one difference I noted is that there seem to be a lot more questions written in English in that site. Using my own experience in German, I can speak it as a foreign language, but writing is much harder. In German there are so many rules and declensions to be aware of when writing a grammatically correct text that I find it easier to ask questions in English. I think the same applies to Portuguese learners, it would be easier to write questions in English (any non-native Portuguese speaker can confirm that?) and even for our question/answers to show up on Google.

As English is the *de facto* language for internet I think we should strive to write more (*interesting*) questions and (*good quality*) answers in English. That should bring more visitors from search engines and  that is the main point we should develop for Portuguese SE to survive the Public Beta phase.

Just to be sure, I counted the top 100 newest questions in both Portuguese and German SE and I found 23 to be in English here in Portuguese SE (mostly from a few 2 or 3 users) and 48 in German SE! That's a remarkable difference, twice as more, and nearly half of the questions in German SE are in English. Perhaps that 50%-50% should be our first benchmark.

Comment: I agree that posts in English will attract more viewers. I've never asked a question in English though. I find a little odd asking in English a question that will take a fluent Portuguese speaker to answer. I have included an English  translation of the Portuguesse title in some questions though. I'm not sure whether that's good enough to show in engine searchs?

Comment: I'm sorry but the whole point is to have questions in other languages. So, I disagree about asking more questions in English about Portuguese.

Comment: @Lambie At the moment our [main problem](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64172/portuguese-language) with Portuguese.SE is the sheer amount of questions asked per day, whether English or Portuguese written. We need 20 times the current rate to be able to graduate. Perhaps having more Portugese written will boost our search-engine hits. YMMV, but I really feel it limits askers to those with a little more knowledge of the language and what we need right now is more and more questions.

Comment: @gmauch [[sheer number of something usually means a lot.]] But, OK, I understand. I am not saying there shouldn't be any English; I am saying that the site is directed at Portuguese speakers, mostly. Just like for English, there is ELL and ELU. Should those sites take more questions in foreign languages? What's the point of a language-specific site if the main focus is English??

Comment: @Lambie. I used my own experience with the Geman language and German.SE. A few years learning it and I traveled a couple times in Germany only using german for communication, but still feel unsafe writing on it. If I was required to write only in German on German.SE my questions and answers there would be either of less quality, shorter, or I would have not written them at all. It takes a good amount of effort to learn a new language and before being fluent it makes sense to use another one to convey information to others, and my usage of _sheer_, intended to be an emphasis just shows that!

Comment: @gmauch You are missing my point entirely. I speak four languages and English is my mother tongue. But the point of all these language sites is to address issues in those languages. Not to make it all refer to English. No one says you can't ask a question about German in English but I disagree there should be more like that, to make it SEO friendly.

Comment: @Lambie IMHO English (or a mix of English and another language) is needed to ask questions in other languages SE and it's good for StackExchange, as it broadens the audience able to read and write more basic questions on a foreign language. At least, being able to ask questions in one language about another one has helped me learn a few languages. Anyway your point is a valid one, so please write an answer with your reasons and let's try to build a consensus around it.

Answer (score 9):

[Vote early, and vote often.](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/)

Your screenshot shows five metrics.  Voting directly addresses one of them: it increases the number of "avid users."

But that's just a small part of the picture.  Voting also encourages good contributors to keep contributing, which drives additional content (both questions and answers) and ultimately traffic as well. Thus voting also indirectly contributes to the other metrics.

Right now only 3 people have the Civic Duty badge (300+ votes) and just 15 have the Vox Populi badge (40 votes in one day).  That's out of 112 who have answered a question, and 266 who have put something in their "About Me" section of the profile.  We can do better!

In the words of Jeff Atwood:

> Voting is as crucial to our community as it is to any democracy. As a moderator, or merely a citizen of the site -- please exercise your right to vote by voting early and voting often!

Comment: I get my Vox Populi badge right now. Doing my job :-P

Answer (score 8):

I've noticed that Portuguese SE's SEO is currently not so good. With some searches using vague terms, i.e. without including "stackexchange" or 
anything closely related to Portuguese SE in the search, it rarely appears on the first page. The first page is 99% of times sufficient to the user and there's a 1% chance that the user goes to the second page, and even less to go to the third, and so on.

Here I list some searches and the page in which Portuguese SE appeared:

[image]

Now some narrower searches:

[image]

Out of 20 searches, in just 7 of them Portuguese SE was on the first page, in which 5 out of these 7 needed narrowing.

One of the things to do so it could get a bit better is making the question title and body more "search engine friendly", i.e. adding keywords in them, like, for example, "diferença" or "difference" to "word-choice" questions (with proper context, not just throw a bunch of words nonsensically). This boosts Google's relevance rate to Portuguese SE pages, as is noticeable in the tests above.

But what's the point of all that I'm saying? The point is that the more Portuguese SE is noticed by *search engines*, the more ***people*** will notice and access it, increasing the visits/day, and consequently boosting the results priority for Portuguese SE, and consequently being noticed by more visitors, and possibly them getting interested in joining and/or asking questions, and that way increasing the questions per day.

Another way to increase users/visitors is the good ol' spreading of the word about Portuguese SE, be it for friends or the public.

Also, in order to increase the users reputation, votes are never too much, as this user with [his answer with it's 24.000+ upvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array#answer-11227902) can say very well, lol XD. Ahem. So the focus, at least for now, should be the low rep users, but don't just upvote any answer/question like crazy. If an answer is well written and correct, and a question is interesting or well written and upvotable (i.e. not homework, "where do I start", etc., questions), upvote it with no mercy.

These are far from being miraculous solutions, but if they help, AWWW YEAH, no doubt!

Answer (score 7):

Since this site is intended for

`linguists, teachers, and learners wanting to discuss the finer points of the Portuguese language`,

and **apparently most of the users are neither teachers nor linguistics, we shoud try and attract them.**

Update: 19-04-07. **Site main indicators** (from http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64172/portuguese-language)

`Date   YYMMDD |150722|150728|150731|150815|151106|160713|160821|170501|190407`

`Days in beta  |   7  |   13 |  16  |  31  | 114  |  365 |  403 |  656 |  1331`

`private/public|   private   |                 public ->                      |`

---

`Question/day  |  27.8|  17.1|   5.4|   3.7|   1.3|     1|   1.1|   0.2|  0.4 | Needs Work`

`Answered  %   |   95 |   95 |   96 |    98|    98|    95|    95|    97|   96 | Excellent`

---

`Total users   |  228 |   238|   245|   333|   566|  1132|  1222|  1855| 3540 | Okay`

`200+ rep users|   50 |    53|    53|    65|    76|   105|   111|   132|  146 |`

`2k+ rep users |   -  |    - |    - |    - |     8|    14|    14|    15|   19 |`

`3k+ rep users |   -  |    - |    - |    - |     2|     4|     5|     9|   11 |`

---

`Answer ratio  |   1.5|   1.5|   1.5|   1.6|   1.7|   1.7|   1.8|   1.8|  1.8 | Okay`

---

`Visits/day    |   229|   159|   134|   188|   405|  1844|  2178|  3859|  8210| Excellent`

Update: Screen shot dated 19-04-07 
(from [Area 51 page for Portuguese Language StackExchange](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64172/portuguese-language))

[image]

Answer (score 2):

My suggestions:

(i) Might sound obvious, but promoting discussions using social networks and alternative channels is probably the surest path for recruiting novel users. **Relevant note**: I understand many users at SE hold aliased profiles in a number of SE communities wherein they'd prefer to remain anonymous. For these users, I'd encourage re-defining privacy settings as to hide these parallel affiliations from their profiles, and help promote question discussions online.

(ii) Avoiding flooding the comments area with chatty remarks is a recommendation I'd encourage here. I am a user of some other SE communities, and other Q&A websites aimed at sharing knowledge and discussing facts. My recent contact with this specific SE website is that comments too often include conversation posts, and others challenging the questioner or answerer into some imperious debate. This is a bit discouraging in Q&A websites, where most visitors seek specific information and not "yet another online dispute".

(iii) I do not know how to achieve that, but I think this community would greatly benefit from international contributors who are native speakers of Portuguese. I understand Brazil is by far the greatest of such nations, but some diversity would surely add a lot of colour to ongoing threads.

Comment: The following parallel discussion is a useful read: https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229/length-of-answers?noredirect=1&lq=1         Answers in this specific SE community do often look needlessly long.

Comment: Comments can be useful and fun. The thing with comments is they’re just as helpful and sensible as the commenter. I find that a bit of thought before posting a comment helps: it is fairly easy for a commenter to sound aggressive even when one does not intend to.

Comment: My main point is that I see a lot of conversational comments, contrasting with few active chat rooms. Some of the most frequent commenters seldom contribute with any answers. Most users and readers new to SE come searching for specific info and help.

Comment: I personally find that the comments bring a bit of levity and friendliness to the community, and that this makes the community a bit more appealing. From the point of view of desire for growth of the community, I think that this is positive. But I also understand your point of view, Scientist, and it's the one I adopt in more... populous communities.

Comment: @ANeves Sure: nothing against relevant comments at all. However in this specific SE community there is a lot of chat that goes on in the comments section. Combined with awfully long answers (see linked discussion in the 1st relevant comment here) it'll dissolve the points of interest to visiting readers.